# Summation in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to create a dictionary in python by using for loop

```
CPO     1
CL      1
SL      1
EL      1
CPO     1
SL      1
CPO     1
```

**So the expected result should be as follow
{'CPO':3,'CL':1,'SL':2,'EL':1}**

I tried this:

```
avail = defaultdict(list)
    cpo = cl = sl= el = 0
    for i in hr_line_id:
        if i.leave_code == 'CPO':
            cpo = cpo + i.no_of_days
            avail['cpo'].append(cpo)
        elif i.leave_code == 'CL':
            cl = cl + i.no_of_days
            avail['cl'].append(cl)
        elif i.leave_code == 'SL':
            sl = sl + i.no_of_days
            avail['sl'].append(sl)
    print avail
```

Comment: perfect job for `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd second the use of `collections.Counter` in the comments, but to adjust your current code, something like this should work:

```
avail = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for i in hr_line_id:
    if i.leave_code == 'CPO':
        avail['cpo'] += i.no_of_days
    elif i.leave_code == 'CL':
        avail['cl'] += i.no_of_days
    elif i.leave_code == 'SL':
        avail['sl'] += i.no_of_days
print avail
```

Per the comments, the `if` chain here is adding a lot of noise. Assuming the target key isn't a function of the input (like `.lower()`) and/or you only want to allow a certain set of keys, something like this would probably be preferred:

```
avail = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
keyMapping = {
  'CPO': 'cpo',
  'CL' : 'cl',
  'SL' : 'sl'
}
for i in hr_line_id:
  if i.leave_code in keyMapping:
    avail[keyMapping[i.leave_code]] += i.no_of_days
  else:
    pass # handle unexpected key
print avail
```

Comment: You could write `defaultdict(int)`, and replace all those `if`s with `avail[i.leave_code.lower()] += i.no_of_days`

Comment: @EricDuminil Agreed on the key mappings; I just didn't want to assume the relationship was more than coincidence for this subset of keys. At a minimum I would encapsulate the mapping somewhere (dictionary or function). Regarding the `int` versus `lambda`, personally I find the `lambda` clearer (more explicit) and easier to maintain (if I want to change the default to something that doesn't happen to have a convenient constructor).

Comment: in that case create a dict to migrate old => new keys, avoid those ifs

Comment: @ryachza: Fair enough. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Added the alternative.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @JeanFrancoisFabre, this is the perfect example for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

text = """CPO     1
CL      1
SL      1
EL      1
CPO     1
SL      1
CPO     1"""

count = Counter()

for line in text.split("\n"):
    k,v = line.split()
    count[k] += int(v)

print(count)
Counter({'CPO': 3, 'SL': 2, 'CL': 1, 'EL': 1})
```

If you want lowercase keys, you could use `count[k.lower()] += int(v)`:

```
Counter({'cpo': 3, 'sl': 2, 'cl': 1, 'el': 1})
```

If the quantity is always `1`, you could simply write a one-liner:

```
Counter(line.split()[0] for line in text.split("\n"))
# Counter({'CPO': 3, 'SL': 2, 'CL': 1, 'EL': 1})
```

Comment: make it `count = Counter(line.split() for line in text.split("\n"))` in one line

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Something's missing... Did you mean `line.split()[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

How about this slightly shorter version with Counter?

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter((i.leave_code.lower(), i.no_of_days) for i in hr_line_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it using loop:

```
text = """CPO     1
CL      1
SL      1
EL      1
CPO     1
SL      1
CPO     1"""

text_split = text.split() # split the text [CPO, 1, CL, 1 and so on]
dict_k = text_split[0::2] # values at odd index
dict_v = text_split[1::2] # values at even index

dict_t = {}

for k, v in zip(dict_k, dict_v):
    dict_t[k] = dict_t.get(k, 0) + int(v)

print(dict_t)

# output:{'SL': 2, 'CPO': 3, 'EL': 1, 'CL': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Except counter you can simply loop.

```
avail = {}
for i in hr_line_id:
    if i.leave_code in avail:
        avail[i.leave_code] += i.no_of_days
    else
        avail[i.leave_code] = i.no_of_days
```